# Can you have an aura attached to an aura that is itself attached to the first aura?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This question was inspired by [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/BadMtgCombos/comments/dd2qlw/feedback_loop/) post on [/r/BadMtgCombos](https://www.reddit.com/r/BadMtgCombos/).

[image]

In the post, the user makes use of three copies of [Feedback](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFeedback%5d) and [Aura Graft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAura%20Graft%5d) to get Feedback 1 attached to Feedback 2, Feedback 2 attached to Feedback 3, and Feedback 3 attached to Feedback 1, creating a "Feedback Loop".

Is it possible to remove a Feedback from this bad combo, and have two Feedbacks attached to each other?

Comment: The person who made that post also wrote the following comment on it: "Two would definitely work. I only used three because it was easier to present visually."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and I think you only need two Feedbacks and Aura Graft (and an arbitrary other enchantment). Just use Aura Graft on Feedback 1 and have it enchant Feedback 2.

While the rules mention that

> 303.4d An Aura can’t enchant itself. If this occurs somehow, the Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard.

there's no such rule forbidding 'mutual' enchantments.